# pass the name of a file in to a hidden field?

Tags: php, file, hidden

How can i grab whatever the value of is in this line of code e.g. the value would be file.php

```
include filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

and then place it in to a hidden field that looks like this

```
 <input type="hidden" name="file_name" value="">
```

so that the placed value can be used to save to whatever the input is to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

<input type="hidden" name="file_name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
```

or if you have short_tags turned on

```
<input type="hidden" name="file_name" value="<?=$name?>">
```